# React Native – multiplatform equivalent of OpenLayers for static images

Tags: android, ios, react-native, openlayers-3

I'm building a React Native app for iOS and Android. Our web-based prototype uses OpenLayers 3 to display pins on a static image (rather than a map). In effect, we're using all the map sugar (zooming, panning, and most importantly, marker pins) but without all the geographic underpinnings.

OpenLayers 3 works well for this on the web – we give it an image and some GeoJSON for the marker pins.

Does anyone have any ideas of a good way to do this on native? Of course, worst case we could use a web view for OpenLayers, but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.